# Ansible Tower - How to pass Machine credentials as an extra vars to the job template?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

The job template has an option for "Prompt on Launch" for credentials.

[image]

I want to pass the credentials name using extra vars. I'm launching these jobs through manageIQ and so I want the user to select the credentials and manageIQ should pass it as extra vars to AWX Tower.

[image]

Any idea what is the parameter for it? For example, in order to pass ssh username, we use "ansible_ssh_user".  I expect something similar is there for credentials? If that's possible would the value for the extra vars be just the credentials name?

I tried `ansible_private_key_file` as the extra vars name with the value `Zabbix` but I get the error that no such file exists (Zabbix).

My workaround right now is to store the ssh_key_file inside AWX container and when launching the job we set the `ansible_private_key_file` to `/tmp/test.pem`. But we actually want to select the name of the credentials from AWX tower instead of storing the keys inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

> *Any idea what is the parameter for it? ... I expect something similar is there for credentials? If that's possible would the value for the extra vars be just the credentials name?*

According Ansible Tower documentation [Credentials](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html) you can make (additional) credentials available via variable names and facts.

For Machine Credential you can get username and password parameters directly from facts:

```yaml
vars:
  machine:
    username: '{{ ansible_user }}'
    password: '{{ ansible_password }}'
```

For [Network Credential](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html#network) which I use additionally in some playbooks I get username and password parameters from the job runtime environment via

```yaml
vars:
  network:
    username: '{{ lookup("env", "ANSIBLE_NET_USERNAME") }}'
    password: '{{ lookup("env", "ANSIBLE_NET_PASSWORD") }}'
```

since currently there is no other way to specify two different Machine Credentials in one [Job Template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html). Other Credential Names are listed in the documentation too.

To inject further credentials you could use

```yaml
extra_vars:
  my_pass: '{{ my_pass }}'
  my_user: '{{ my_user }}'
```

and access them with

```yaml
ansible_user: "{{ my_user }}"
ansible_password: "{{ my_pass }}"
```

Even the direct way is working

```bash
ansible test --extra-vars="ansible_user=${ACCOUNT} ansible_password=${PASSWORD}" --become --module-name shell --args "echo $(hostname)"
```

to make a connection. So in your case, your [extra variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime) could be

```yaml
---
ansible_user: USER
ansible_password: PASSWORD
```

or

```bash
--extra-vars="ansible_user=USER ansible_password=PASSWORD"
```

**Thanks to**

- [How Do I Use Ansible Tower's Credential Parameters (Machine, Network, Cloud) in my Playbook?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3332591)
- [How To Use Multiple Machine Credentials For A Job Template In Ansible Tower?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3877061)

Comment: Is there no way to call `zabbix` creds directly? That zabbix creds is actually a SSH key for AWS key pair. 

The examples you have showed means that I have to specify username and password or maybe ssh_key. But I want to invoke the creds saved inside awx tower (example: Zabbix)

Comment: example: Extra vars would be like `tower_credentials = Zabbix`

Comment: @John, according your screenshot the "Zabbix" credentials are stored as of type Machine Credentials. You could also try to introduce [Custom Credentials](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credential_types.html). However, according your comment and further description, you like to access credentials from within the Tower Environment. To do so, a playbook needs to be running already. What might work is, providing any credentials and overwrite `ansible_user` and `ansible_password` at runtime.