# Ansible AWX / Tower - Use Vault credential in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower, ansible-vault

In Ansible AWX I created a Vault-credential (named: user-pw). Now I want to use that password in a playbook. But it doesn't work.

I created a template, add the Vault-credential (at the credential input). In the playbook I used the variable "{{ user-pw }}" at the place where the password should be.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the AWX Vault password in the playbook as a variable?

This is the vault credential screen:
[image: Vault credential]

And this is the template screen:
[image: Template]

And this is the test playbook:

```
---
- name: Vaulttest
  hosts: win

  tasks:
    - name: View user pw
      debug:
        msg: "{{ user-pw }}"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! I used custom credentials the wrong way.

I created a complete new custom credential (under Administration - Credential Types).

Input configuration:

```
fields:
  - id: pass
    type: string
    label: password
    secret: true
required:
  - pass
```

Injector configuration:

```
extra_vars:
  pass: '{{pass}}'
```

Then I created the credential with the custom credential. Filled in the password.

Use the password variable in a playbook like this:

```
- name: Test
  module:
    username: testuser
    password: "{{ pass }}"
```

At last, add the custom credential to the template.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you.  I am using Tower and struggled to get a vault credential working.  Following your instructions did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

According the very minimal description it seems to be the correct approach for using [Credentials](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html), even [Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html#vault).

To debug [Custom Credential Types](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credential_types.html) I am using usually

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Get environment
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_env }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Get environment] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            ...
            "TEST_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD": "test_password", 
            "TEST_ACCOUNT_NAME": "test_account", 
            ...
        }
        ...
```

if such Custom Test Credentials are configured. This is working for AWX/Tower. You can then follow up with

- [Ansible Tower - How to pass credentials as an extra vars to the job template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71030474/6771046)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I use "{{ ansible_env }}" it shows a lot of info but not the password I set at the vault. I edited my post with some more info.

Comment: @ND90, I see, after a short test I've got the same behavior. Going to setup an other test, which might take some time. Just to note, in your screenshot the Vault password name is `userpw`, whereby it is in your playbook `user-pw`. It is recommended to **not** use dashes in variable names at all. You may switch to `_` instead.

Comment: Alright, removed the dashes. Didn't know that!