# Ansible Tower: Run tower-cli asking for vault pass

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower, ansible-vault

I'm working with Ansible Tower and using Vault credential.

When I launch it using the graphical interface of Ansible Tower (I add the credential when it's prompted), it work well.

When I try with the `tower-cli` line, I get this message:

```json
{"failed": true, "msg": "Decryption failed (no vault secrets would found t
hat could decrypt)"
```

I found that I need to add something like `--ask-vault-pass` but it is listed as an unknown argument when I add to my `tower-cli` line, so it work only with `ansible-playbook` command.

How can I ask for vault password with `tower-cli`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take note that there is a difference between Ansible Engine, the command line tools `ansible` for ad-hoc commands and `ansible-playbook` for executing playbooks, and [Ansible Tower](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/intro-ansible-tower). According the [documentation](https://tower-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Ansible Tower is

> *a GUI and REST interface for Ansible that supercharges it by adding RBAC, centralized logging, autoscaling/provisioning callbacks, graphical inventory editing, and more ... tower-cli is a command line tool for Ansible Tower. It allows Tower commands to be easily run from the Unix command line*

As you have already found out

> *I need to add something like `--ask-vault-pass` but it is listed as an unknown argument when I add to my `tower-cli` ... it work only with `ansible-playbook` command*

this is the expected behavior.

The solution lays in the way you have described

> *When I launch it using the graphical interface of Ansible Tower (I add the credential when it's prompted), it work well*

For further automation you will need to configure your Ansible Tower [Credentials](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html) store and setup a credential of type [Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html#vault). Based on the there stored password, AWX will forward the vault password to Ansible Engine. Ansible Engine will then use that password to unlock the vault and your playbook can run.

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible AWX / Tower - Use Vault credential in playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71253679/6771046)
- [Ansible Tower - How to pass Machine credentials as an extra vars to the job template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71030474/6771046)

Comment: Thank for the answer, I already created a Vault credential but I can't find how to forward the vault password (my command line is ``tower-cli job launch ...``
(I should have added more context, I'm using tower-cli for launching my pipelines in Gitlab)

Comment: @Gabriel, you may have a look into [Ansible AWX / Tower - Use Vault credential in playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71252487/).

Comment: Thank you, I found (here : https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli/issues/629 second message) that I needed to add the parameter --credentials="name_vaul" in my ``tower-cli job launch`` command