# Ansible Tower: Custom Credential Type

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I created a Custom Credential in Ansible Tower and need to use it in a role.

The credential name is `custom_cred` -> this has 2 keys `custom username` and `custom password`.

I've tried `hostvars[inventory_hostname][custom_cred]['custom username']` but its not working.

Comment: Could you please share the input configuration.

Comment: Does your Custom Credential key do have really key names with space? Can you furthermore share the output from `ansible_env`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug your [Custom Credential Types](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credential_types.html) you could use

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Get environment
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_env }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Get environment] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            ...
            "custom_username": "username", 
            "custom_password": "********", 
            ...
        }
        ...
```

if such Custom Test Credentials are configured. This is working for AWX/Tower. You can then follow up with

- [Ansible Tower - How to pass credentials as an extra vars to the job template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71030474/6771046)