# When multiple credentials are attached to a job template, how do I differentiate the credentials?

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible Automation Platform. I have a job template with multiple credentials attached. The way I understand it, the credential username is passed in as `"{{ user }}"` and the password is `"{{ pass }}"`. My question is since I have more than one credential, when I use `"{{ user }}"` which username is used? And how would I be able to use one or the other?

Comment: Indeed, that could become a little bit tricky. Does [Ansible Tower - How to pass Machine credentials as an extra vars to the job template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71030474/6771046) or [Ansible Tower: Custom Credential Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422397/6771046) answer your question? At least it should explain something, or you could debug and narrow down ...